# Formatting date in xslt

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

I'm trying to format a certain date format in xslt. This is the format:

> 2012-7-19

I'd like to convert this to a numerical value in xslt for sorting, so that the above would become:

> 20120719

The problem is that single months/days don't have a 0 in front of them. So I need to somehow add that in front of single digit months/days, but not in front of months/days that have two digits. Does anyone know how I can do this?

I have this so far:

```
<xsl:value-of select="concat(
    substring(substring-after(substring-after(./AirDate, '/'),'/'),0,5),
    substring(substring-after(./AirDate, '/'), 0, 3),
    substring-before(./AirDate, '/'))"/>
```

but that occasionally throws in a `/` for single digit days, and doesn't put a 0 in front of single digit months/days

I don't have the ability to change the data source before passing it to the xslt, and I have to use xslt version 1.0.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think format-number will do the trick.

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" />

    <xsl:variable name="date" select="'2007-3-19'" />
    <xsl:template name="format_date" >
        <xsl:param name ="date" />
        <xsl:variable name ="year" select="substring-before($date, '-')" />
        <xsl:variable name ="month_and_day" select="substring-after($date, '-')" />
        <xsl:variable name ="day" select="substring-after($month_and_day, '-')" />
        <xsl:variable name ="month" select="substring-before($month_and_day, '-')" />
        <xsl:value-of select="$year"/>
        <xsl:value-of select="format-number($month, '00')"/>
        <xsl:value-of select="format-number($day, '00')"/>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="/" >
        <xsl:call-template name="format_date" >
            <xsl:with-param name ="date" select="$date"/>
        </xsl:call-template>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm sure there's a more elegant way of doing this even with XSLT 1.0, but this rather brutish solution is one option:

#### Stylesheet

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="text" version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"/>

  <xsl:variable name="HYPHEN" select="'-'"/>

  <xsl:template name="zero-pad">
    <xsl:param name="number"/>

    <xsl:choose>
      <xsl:when test="string-length($number) = 1">
        <xsl:value-of select="concat('0', $number)"/>
      </xsl:when>
      <xsl:otherwise>
        <xsl:value-of select="$number"/>
      </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template name="format-date">
    <xsl:param name="date"/>

    <xsl:variable name="year" select="substring-before($date, $HYPHEN)"/>
    <xsl:variable name="month-and-day"
      select="substring-after($date, concat($year, $HYPHEN))"/>

    <xsl:variable name="month">
      <xsl:call-template name="zero-pad">
        <xsl:with-param name="number"
          select="substring-before($month-and-day, $HYPHEN)"/>
      </xsl:call-template>
    </xsl:variable>

    <xsl:variable name="day">
      <xsl:call-template name="zero-pad">
        <xsl:with-param name="number"
          select="substring-after($month-and-day, $HYPHEN)"/>
      </xsl:call-template>
    </xsl:variable>

    <xsl:value-of select="number(concat($year, $month, $day))"/>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:call-template name="format-date">
      <xsl:with-param name="date" select="'2012-7-19'"/>
    </xsl:call-template>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

#### Output

```
20120719
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a combination of `substring-after` and `substring-before` to extract the pieces, and then handle them as numbers instead than strings - i.e. uses multiplications and additions to generate the final value.

Something like this:

```
<xsl:variable name="sep" select="'-'"/>
<xsl:variable name="date" select="."/>
<xsl:value-of select="substring-after(substring-after($date, $sep),$sep) + substring-before(substring-after($date, $sep),$sep)*100 + substring-before($date, $sep)*10000"/>
```

setting the `sep` and `date` variables to the separator to use and the original date string respectively (in your question the sample uses `-` as the separator, but the XSLT uses `/`)

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
<xsl:value-of select="concat(substring(date, 7, 4), '-', substring(date, 4, 2), '-', substring(date, 1, 2))"/>
```