# How to Get Correctly formatted date using Xslt?

Tags: xslt

I have a xslt code for getting the date from the database.the code is working correctly and I got the output ,but the problem is the date is not in correct format.here is the result.

output: 2013-05-07T11:27:46.7+02:00

my code is

```
 <xsl:variable name="lastchange" select="shop:ExecStoredProcedure('kt_Lastchange',concat('@account:',$accid,',@itemnumber:',id))"></xsl:variable>
    <textarea>
    <xsl:value-of select ="$lastchange"/>
    </textarea>
```

anyone can help for getting the correctly format of date?

Comment: This is nearly a duplicate question. Have a look to this [soltuion](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16113040/2115381).

Comment: As you already use a xslt extension, it might be easier to add another extension namespace for java.util and call SimpleDateFormat  with the right format string ...

Answer (score 1):

If you are using

XSLT 1.0 version, use EXSLT - date:format-date date extension

XSLT 2.0 version, use built-in: Formatting Dates and Times date extension

**Code**

```
<xsl:variable name="dt" as="xs:dateTime" select="xs:dateTime('2012-10-21T22:10:15')"/>
<xsl:value-of select="format-dateTime($dt, '[Y0001]/[M01]/[D01]')"/>
```